# How to obtain imaginary time Green's function from real time Green's function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions, wick-rotation

Take the following real time time-order Green's function as an example:
\begin{equation}
i G(x, t)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{t}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{t}\right], t>0 \\ \frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{-t}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{-t}\right], t<0\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Then, using the relation $t \rightarrow-\dot{i} \tau$, it can be transform to imaginary time:
$$\mathcal{G}(x, \tau)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{-i \tau}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{-i \tau}\right], \tau>0 \\ \frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{i \tau}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{i \tau}\right], \tau<0\end{array}\right.$$
However, I can also rewrite the real time time-order Green's function as:
$$i G(x, t)=\frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{|t|}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{|t|}\right]$$
If so, its imaginary time partner will be:
$$\mathcal{G}(x, \tau)=\frac{1}{\alpha \sqrt{|\tau|}} \exp \left[-\beta \frac{x^{2}}{|\tau|}\right]$$

#### question

1. I am confused that why these two results are different?
2. We know that the imaginary time Green's function (bosonic) is periodic with respect to $\beta$, i.e. $\mathcal{G}(\tau)=\mathcal{G}(\tau+\beta)$, but both two results seems like violate this rule. Or, does this indicate that the above transformation is only correct for $\tau \in[0, \beta)$?

Comment: Concerning conventions are you following a reference?